# Anyone know of a book or documentation like MFC Internals for Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, sdk, cross-platform, qt-creator

I have recently read MFC Internals (ISBN 9780201407211) and it helped me greatly gain an intimate understanding of how MFC works and increased productivity about 100 fold. I was wondering now that I am into Qt, is there any book or documentation out there like this? I have been having a hard time finding straight-up documentation on Qt, it always seems to be beat-around=the-bush style of documentation (they tell you how to build the house, but not how to cut down the tree) ??

Comment: "Use the source, Luke!"

Comment: Unfortunately, this is often the case in open source/ free software world. If you find the Qt tutorial like this, let the others know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to try developing your own application. Just start from a basic application like calculator. Add a few widgets to it and code it as you go. For reference use "C++ gui programming with Qt4" mentioned by Zlatomir. I have recently designed a whole GUI using Qt. I drew its screenshots on Inkscape to get a prototype look and afterwards I started working on designer to fulfill each functionality. Then I implemented the code and I repeated the designing and coding steps. Also, the best help will be Qt Assistant - its sufficiently complete, no Internet required so save times and simple to use. Going my way, you will not only learn Qt in short interval after which you can go through the book to know what tips and tricks you might not know, but also it will be interesting so that you may not give up like many others who just fall midway through the reading part. Warning - Doing this way, you will also know about pitfalls/drawbacks of Qt and how to not go that way.

This is one of the links I found last night. I went through 2 pages and found it might make your life a bit easier - http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/

Comment: thanks for that very thurough answer, i appreciate it very much and that helps out alot.

Answer (score 1):

I have not read the MFC book you mentioned, but the Qt framework i learned by reading from *"C++ gui programming with Qt4"* (the first edition is available as a free download) and *"Foundation of Qt development"* and also it's worth mentioning [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-basic-concepts.html) documentation page, that contains links to the basic concepts of Qt framework.

Comment: thank you for that, i will definitely check out that book --- thanks for the link too since there are so many links out there for this it's hard sometimes to find exactly the right page even when searching through only one site.